# How to replace a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to change all credit card last 10 numbers to `**********`

For example `49601111111111` to `4960**********`.

Please help

Comment: And where do you work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Substr(cardnumber, 1, 4)||'**********' from 
  yourcardtable;
```

Comment: how do you know that cardnumber has 14 characters?

Comment: May vary some have 15 and others 16. So it is better to avoid hard coding number of digits in `substr`. Instead use `length` (see above)

Answer (score 1):

This works even when number of digits in credit card is not known or varies and with up to 19 digits. As per standards card numbers should have maximum 19 digits [Reference WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number)

**Query:**

```
  select REPLACE('1234567890123456789',substr('1234567890123456789',
    length('1234567890123456789')-10+1),'**********') from dual;
  ---Output:
           123456789**********

 select REPLACE('1234560000000000',substr('1234560000000000',
        length('1234560000000000')-10+1),'**********') from dual;
  ---Output:
           123456**********
```

> PS - Update made to incorporate `card_number` in case card has more than 20 digits.
>   credits :   `Florin Ghita`

```
 select
    substr('01234567890123456789',1,length('01234567890123456789')-10) || '**********'
    from dual;

 ---Output
 `0123456789**********`

 with Credit_Card_details AS
(
select '1234567890123456789' as CARD_NUMBER from dual
) select CARD_NUMBER 
AS String,
length(CARD_NUMBER)
AS  string_length,
REPLACE(CARD_NUMBER,substr(CARD_NUMBER,length(CARD_NUMBER)-10+1),'**********') 
AS New_string,
length(REPLACE(CARD_NUMBER,substr(CARD_NUMBER,length(CARD_NUMBER)-10+1),'**********')) 
AS New_string_length
from Credit_Card_details
```

[image: Test_output]

Comment: Try with `'01234567890123456789' as CARD_NUMBER`. Just don't use replace in this problem.

Comment: Maximum card number for any bank is 19 as per `ISO standards`, read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number and this works fine for digits <= 19

Comment: Updated answer to incorporate 20 digits ( in case a card has >19 digits)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set credit_number = rpad(substr(credit_number, 1, 4), length(credit_number), '*');
```

Comment: how do you know that cardnumber has 14 characters?

Comment: I don't know how long the credit card number is.  That's why I look for the overall length of the value and rpad it with "*" after the initial 4.

Answer (score -1):

try this query:

```
update Table1 set Credit_number = SUBSTRING(Credit_number, 1, 4)+'**********'
```